# html static page position after refresh

Tags: html, static, refresh

I have a page where I would like it to remain static after refresh and does not default back to the top page again as it will disrupt the position I was viewing it last. Hence I have all the time to scroll down again to find the area I was viewing last. Is there a way of eliminating the burden of scrolling down again?

Comment: in asp.net theres a proprerty for this in the page directive. dont have the js offhand though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of [retaining scroll position using PHP](http://patrickfoley.com/2005/01/21/scroll-saver/).

Here's an example [for ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetjunkies.ddj.com/Article/E474B0FC-20D2-48B3-93B5-DC4CB3C4A1AB.dcik).

If those don't suffice, doing a google search for "retaining scroll position" will provide many more examples.

Comment: Have you got any example for ASP.NET VB please?

Comment: The link for PHP is not available.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry - I took down the blog referenced above (noticed in redirect stats), but the post is still available from archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20050508195342/patrickfoley.com/2005/01/21/scroll-saver/

Here's the complete PHP example from that page:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test</TITLE>
<script>
  function SaveScrollXY() {
    document.Form1.ScrollX.value = document.body.scrollLeft;
    document.Form1.ScrollY.value = document.body.scrollTop;
  }
  function ResetScrollPosition() {
    var hidx, hidy;
    hidx = document.Form1.ScrollX;
    hidy = document.Form1.ScrollY;
    if (typeof hidx != 'undefined' && typeof hidy != 'undefined') {
      window.scrollTo(hidx.value, hidy.value);
    }
  }
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="ResetScrollPosition()">
  <form name="Form1" id="Form1" method="post"
    onsubmit="SaveScrollXY()" action="index.php">
    <input name="ScrollX" id="ScrollX" type="hidden"
      value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['ScrollX'] ?>" />
    <input name="ScrollY" id="ScrollY" type="hidden"
      value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['ScrollY'] ?>" />
    <p>This is just a paragraph to make a very long page.</p>
    …
    <P>This is just a paragraph to make a very long page.</P>
    <P>
      <input name="TextBox1" type="text"
        value="<?php $v = $_REQUEST['TextBox1']; echo $v ? $v + 1 : 1 ?>"
        readonly="readonly" id="TextBox1" /></P>
    <P>
      <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Post Form"
        id="Button1" /></P>
  </form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```