# Refresh html page to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

Currently this is my problem. I'm using jquery scrollTop for parallaxing, and if i restart the page it returns to the current page and some bugs occured because it is not refreshed from the top of the page. Is there any way to do this? I've already tried some of the examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486527/reload-browser-does-not-reset-page-to-top). I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: **Try following Urls:**

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640603/html-window-refresh-top-of-page][1]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486527/reload-browser-does-not-reset-page-to-top][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640603/html-window-refresh-top-of-page
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486527/reload-browser-does-not-reset-page-to-top

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, i need to suppouse.
Check if your URL have an [anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp), the expected behavior it's scroll to the element informed in the URL, like this: http://yourdomain.com/#example.
Please put a reference to the code if it isn't the solution.